# C++ Estilo al escribir codigo

Tags: c++

Hola estoy tratando de aprender C++, pero noto que cada quien tiene diferente estilo al momento de escribir el codigo

Alguien podria explicarme lo que hace este pedazo de codigo?

```
{
  for(
   c = 0 ;c<4 ; c++) 
  {
    desglose[a][c]=0;
  }
}
```

Se que es un ciclo `for`, pero a que se refiere con

```
desglose[a][c]=0;
```

¿Existe otra forma de interpretarlo?

Comment: `desglose[a][c]` puede significar diferentes cosas dependiendo de si `desglose` es una formación bidimensional, una formación unidimensional, una formación de clases o una clase con `operator[]` sobrecargado ¿no tienes más contexto? ¿Cuál es el tipo subyacente de `desglose`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo este link de referencia para que entiendas que [es una matriz](https://www.programarya.com/Cursos/C++/Estructuras-de-Datos/Matrices).

En ese link vas a encontrar mas informacion sobre el tema, de todas formas, si tienes razon, es un ciclo **FOR** que recorre todas las columnas de la posicion **'a'** la cual no sabemos que numero es, y les asigna **0**.

Ejemplo: Suponiendo que tu matris es de **3*3**, esta completamente llena de **'1'** y tu **a = 1**, el dibujo de tu matriz quedaria asi:

[image: Dibujo de matriz]

Espero que te sirva!
Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, pero responder preguntas que están realizadas sin seguir lo definido en [ask] provoca que el sitio tenga contenido de baja calidad, ayúdanos a orientar al OP a crear preguntas de buena calidad que sean útiles para toda la comunidad.

Answer (score 0):

`desglose[][]` está haciendo referencia a un arreglo de dos dimensiones (una matriz). El cual su valor en la posición `[a][c]` está siendo asignado a `0`.

Por ejemplo: Si tienes una matriz de 3X3 se vería algo como estó:

```
   j j j   
i [][][]
i [][][]
i [][][]
```

Si mezclas dos ciclos for (como aparenta ser tu caso) para llenar de ceros la matriz tendrías que hacer algo como esto:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j){
        desglose[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

Donde el primer ciclo for corresponde al valor de tus filas y el del segundo ciclo corresponde a tus columnas.

Podemos verlo de la siguiente manera. En el primer ciclo for, el cual se repite 3 veces se crea un ciclo for, el cual se repite 3 veces. Esto quiere decir que en la primera iteración del primer ciclo for la variable `i` tendrá un valor de `0`. Este valor continuará en `0` por los 3 turnos del segundo ciclo for. Donde la variable `j` irá aumentando.

```
desglose[0][0] = 0; // [variable i][variable j]
desglose[0][1] = 0; // [variable i][variable j]
desglose[0][2] = 0; // [variable i][variable j]
```

Después de cumplir 3 iteraciones dentro del ciclo de la variable `j` se aumenta en 1 el valor de la variable `i` del primer ciclo. Mientras que la variable `j` regresa a un valor de `0` y vuelve a aumentarse 3 veces.

```
desglose[1][0] = 0; // [variable i][variable j]
desglose[1][1] = 0; // [variable i][variable j]
desglose[1][2] = 0; // [variable i][variable j]
```

Esto quiere decir que si el primer ciclo for tiene `n` iteraciones y el segundo ciclo tiene `m` iteraciones se harán un total de `n*m` iteraciones  para llenar la matriz. En este caso es una matriz de `3*3`.